# Mvc 3 Razor, text block in viewpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having a problem with the `<text>` tag. The following code will not run due to the `</tr>` tag near the bottom. If i remove it, it works but it then prints an incorrect table. If i leave it i get the following error: Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

How can i tell razor to ignore such things?
(I also tried to add a text tag around the /tr and also around all html code but that produces this: Encountered end tag "text" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

```
@{                             
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.Model)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        <text><tr class="alternate-row"></text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text><tr></text>
    }

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Firstname
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Surname
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="">george@mainevent.co.za</a>
        </td>
        <td class="options-width">
            <a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a><a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-2 info-tooltip">
            </a><a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-3 info-tooltip"></a><a href="" title="Edit"
                class="icon-4 info-tooltip"></a><a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-5 info-tooltip">
                </a>
        </td>        
    </tr>

}      
}
```

**Update with another question**

Why does Razor even test html-tags?

Comment: Razor tests HTML tags because the parser needs to detect which elements on the page are Razor and which are plain HTML. Treat it very different from how the standard Web Forms View Engine works with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<tr@if (i % 2 == 0) { <text> class="alternate-row"</text> }>
```

or you can set a variable that "holds" your extended html for the `<tr>` tag like this

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.Model)
{
    string ext = "";
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        ext = " class=\"alternate-row\"";
    }

    <tr@ext>
    // ...
```

Thats the simplest solution, or you can create a custom html helper.

More information: [Creating Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

**Update**

Darin said too, what he would create a custom html helper.

I suggest that too, if you need that more than one time.

**conclusion**

first choice is to create a html helper, second is to use my first 
approach (inline if statement) and at last to use a variable.

It does not really depends on "how often" you need that, but if you really need 
that only one time, choose the first approach.
Every of the three solutions are correct, its your decision depending on the time 
you have.

**hope this helps you**

Comment: So you mean that there is no other way to get around this?

Comment: <tr@if (i % 2 == 0) { <text> class="alternate-row"</text> }> works fine but it still feels a bit too much for just one </tr>

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr@Html.Raw(i % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"alternate-row\"" : "")>
    ... some tds
</tr>
```

But personally I would write a custom Html helper to avoid this spaghetti code and have something along the lines of:

```
@using (Html.Tr(i))
{
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Firstname
    </td>    
    ...
}
```

I would also refactor and get rid of the `foreach` loop and replace it with a simple display template call: `@Html.DisplayForModel()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate approach for you using javascript.  Since you are using MVC3, you probably have access to jQuery.  Add this little nugget of javascript ([See jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcmTg/))

```
$(function() {
    $('tr:odd').addClass('alternate-row');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the the `<text>` blocks from around the tr tag in your conditional

Comment: Will not work for <tr class="alternate-row">, tried that already.